# MySQL doesn't start: touch: ./data/mysql/xxx.local.err: No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, mac-osx

My OS is OS X, I installed MySQL Percona via `brew`. Error log of MySQL was `/usr/local/var/mysql/xxx.local.err`. After that I tried to run `mysql_install_db` and rebooted machine. OK, but now I see see in syslog

```
Aug 17 03:17:47 xxx com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[247] (homebrew.mxcl.percona-server[29906]): Exited with code: 1
Aug 17 03:17:47 xxx com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[247] (homebrew.mxcl.percona-server): Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
Aug 17 03:17:58 xxx com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[247] (homebrew.mxcl.percona-server[30026]): Exited with code: 1
Aug 17 03:17:58 xxx com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[247] (homebrew.mxcl.percona-server): Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
...
```

OK, I try to run it manually:

```
$ /usr/lo/usr/local/opt/percona-server/bin/mysqld_safe

130817 03:14:07 mysqld_safe Logging to './data/mysql/xxx.local.err'.
touch: ./data/mysql/xxx.local.err: No such file or directory
chmod: ./data/mysql/xxx.local.err: No such file or directory
130817 03:14:07 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from ./data/mysql
/usr/local/opt/percona-server/bin/mysqld_safe: line 135: ./data/mysql/xxx.local.err: No such file or directory
/usr/local/opt/percona-server/bin/mysqld_safe: line 172: ./data/mysql/xxx.local.err: No such file or directory
touch: ./data/mysql/xxx.local.err: No such file or directory
chown: ./data/mysql/xxx.local.err: No such file or directory
chmod: ./data/mysql/xxx.local.err: No such file or directory
130817 03:14:07 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file ./data/mysql/xxx.local.pid ended
/usr/local/opt/percona-server/bin/mysqld_safe: line 135: ./data/mysql/xxx.local.err: No such file or directory
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Why location of error log was changed from `/usr/local/var/mysql/xxx.local.err` to `./data/mysql/xxx.local.err`?
2. How do I fix it? Creation of dir `/usr/lo/usr/local/opt/percona-server/bin/data/mysql` does not solve the problem.

Comment: mkdir /usr/local/opt/percona-server/data/mysql/

Comment: i believe, ./data/mysql/ is relative to prefix

Comment: Thanks! That dir (relative to my.cnf) already exists, but I changed datadir to absolute path and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer of your first question:**

When you compile a program, you use `"configure --prefix=your primative path"`, `configure` command is capable to classify each path of your program, maintainer of your `mysql server`,separate path of `log files, pid file, binary files, sbin,` and so on.

**Answer of your second question:**

in my.cnf , you can change path of `pid file`. `socket file` ,`basedir`, `datadir` , `tmpdir` and `lc-messages-dir`